# ManyToMany Association (BeanList deferred)

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I have a ManyToMany-Association like this:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model implements RoleHolder {
  @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
  public List<Task> tasks;
}
```

Then I do that:

```
User u = Application.getLocalUser(session());
u.tasks.clear();
for (Task t : tasksToAdd)
  u.tasks.add(t);
u.saveManyToManyAssociations("tasks");
u.update()
```

But when I try to read the Collection in my Controller-Action, there is only a "BeanList deferred"-Message

```
User u = Application.getLocalUser(session());       
return ok(tasks.render(u.tasks));
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Where do you see the message? Inside your template? What do you have in your template?

Comment: I have the same issue, is there a solution now?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message when implementing a @ManyToMany association.

The problem in my case was that I forgot to `save()` (i.e. insert) Entity Y after adding it to List<Y> in Entity X.